# WordPress - get_attached_media what is type name for words documents?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.5.2

I have words documents attached to a post and I want to fetch them when I am on that post.

```
$docs = get_attached_media('attachment', $post->ID);
var_dump($docs);
```

I get nothing. What is the **type name** for documents then? It is not mentioned in [WP site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a detailed description: http://theme.fm/2011/07/how-to-display-post-attachments-in-wordpress-945/

Answer (score 0):

get_attached_media( string $type, int|WP_Post $post )
$type is mime type
you can get the list of mime types here
https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/